# PyCharm outputs a "Non ASCII" error on the terminal

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been making game which is called the riddle game it works semi perfect on pycharm, because the code `os.system("clear")` doesn't work, but it does work on terminal, but there is slightly a problem it return with a a error "Non ASCII" i couldn't understand. How can i fix this?

Either way I try to make the code as simple as possible can anyone check it and if it's too big give me a suggestion to change a rewrite the code please.

```
import random
import sys
import time

riddle1 = "You’re running a race and pass the person in second place. What place are you in now?"
riddle2 = "Imagine you are in a dark room. How do you get out?"
riddle3 = "David's father has three sons : Snap, Crackle and _ _ _ ?"
riddle4 = "You answer me, but I never ask you a question. What am I?"
riddle5 = "The more you take, the more you leave behind. What am I?"
riddle6 = "What comes once in a minute, twice in a moment, but never in a thousand years?"
riddle7 = "What room that ghosts can't get in?"

riddle1_Ans = "You’re in second place. You didn't pass the person in first"
riddle2_Ans = "Stop imagining"
riddle3_Ans = "David"
riddle4_Ans = "A telephone"
riddle5_Ans = "Footsteps"
riddle6_Ans = "m"
riddle7_Ans = "The living room"

riddles_lists = [riddle1, riddle2, riddle3, riddle4, riddle5, riddle6, riddle7]
random_list = random.choice(riddles_lists)


# Welcoming the user

def welcome():
    print("")
    print("\033[1;31;0m", " Welcome to RIDDLES")
    print("\033[1;33;0m", " ")

    answer = input(" Do you want to play the game?Y/N:")

    if answer in ("yes", "y"):
        Introductin()

    else:
        print("Bye....")
        sys.exit()


# RESTART GAME
def restart():
    print(" ")
    ask = input("Do you want to Try? if you say yes the game will restart"
                " if you say no there answer of the riddle will be shown:")

    if ask in ("yes", "y"):
        print("Restarting game.....")
        time.sleep(1)
        play_game()

    if ask in ("no", "n"):
        print("The question was:")
        print(" ")
        print("\033[1;32;0m", random_list)
        print(" ")
        time.sleep(4)
        print("\033[1;35;0m", "The answer is:")
        print(" ")

        time.sleep(1)

        print(".........")
        if random_list == riddle1:
            print(riddle1_Ans)

        if random_list == riddle2:
            print(riddle2_Ans)

        if random_list == riddle3:
            print(riddle3_Ans)

        if random_list == riddle4:
            print(riddle4_Ans)

        if random_list == riddle5:
            print(riddle5_Ans)

        if random_list == riddle6:
            print(riddle6_Ans)

        if random_list == riddle7:
            print(riddle7_Ans)
        print(".........")


# The Game
def Introductin():
    print(" ")
    print("\033[1;36;0m", "Hello there, I'm Zelandini the host of the game. You will be guessing the answer of the " \
                          "coming riddles"
                          ", you have 20 second to guess. Once the time ran out you have the chance to see the answer.")
    print(" ")
    game_start = input("Ready?Y/N:")

    if game_start in ("yes", "y"):
        play_game()

def play_game():
        sec = 1

        print(" ")

        while sec != 4:
            print("Game starts in", sec)

            time.sleep(1)
            sec += 1
            if sec == 4:
                Game_Start()


def Game_Start():
    minutes = 1

    print(" ")
    print("\033[1;32;0m BEGIN!")

    print("..............")
    print("\033[1;32;0m ", "The riddle is", random_list)
    print("..............")

    while minutes != 21:
        print(">>>>", minutes, "seconds")

        time.sleep(1)
        minutes += 1

        if minutes == 21:
            print(" ")
            print("\033[1;34;0m", "TIMES OUT!")
            break

    restart()


welcome()
```

Comment: This does not answer the problem you are having, but to answer your second point - if you are looking for a review of your code - or to make it more elegant you could ask on [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thanks ill keep that in mind

Comment: If those other escape codes work ok in PyCharm, then the clear command `print("\033c")` will probably work too. BTW, you could make that code shorter and simpler by using lists instead of all of those numbered variables.

Comment: But it wont fix the Non ASCII part

Comment: Sorry, I don't have PyCharm, and your code runs without errors in my Linux terminal, although it's a bit annoying that it doesn't let you answer the riddle.

Comment: Can you please add the full error output to the question? Is it just "Non-ASCII" or is it some UnicodeDecode exception? Looking at your code I wonder if ``os.system("clear")`` and raw escape codes for colors are the best way. Have a look if there are some python modules wrapping this much nicer.

Comment: @PM2Ring the problem is that there is Non ASCII code???

Comment: @allo, it's about Non ASCII codes, i don't understand which one??By the way th os.sys thing i got it flow.

Comment: As I said, I don't get any errors when I run that code. If _you_ get an error message you _need_ to put the full error message into your question, starting with the `Traceback` line. You should probably mention which OS you are using, although that code should run correctly on any Unix-like OS. Of course, it won't run correctly on Windows.